# How to access a property named "base" on a dynamic object

Tags: c#, .net, dynamic

I'm trying to access the `IP` property of the object shown below:

```
dynamic results2 = shell2.Invoke();
query["ipAddress"] = results2[0].BaseObject.base.base.IP;
```

[image: Watch window in Visual Studio showing the property results2 (dynamic) > [0] > BaseObject > base > base > IP]

But currently I am getting the following error:

```
Identifier expected; 'base' is a keyword
```

How can I access the `base` property of a `dynamic` object?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because `base` is a keyword, you must prefix it with `@` to use it as an identifier:

```
query["ipAddress"] = results2[0].BaseObject.@base.@base.IP;
```

**UPDATE:** It turns out that the `base` entries in your Watch window actually refer to the *base classes* of `BaseObject`, not to an actual property called `base`. So all you need to write is this:

```
query["ipAddress"] = results2[0].BaseObject.IP;
```

Comment: but i am getting this error  error now "VMware.VimAutomation.ViCore.Impl.V1.Host.Networking.Nic.HostVMKernelVirtualNicImpl' does not contain a definition for 'base'" altohugh from the screen shot i provided i can access BaseObject.base.base...

Comment: Does it work if you just write `results2[0].BaseObject.IP`?